# SqlAlchemy ORM - restricting columns at query time (select) - column_property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I know I can lazy load columns from a table:

```
session.query(MyTable).options(defer(colname) 
      for colname in ['col4', 'col5', ..,  'colN'])
```

I only want the first 3 columns, so can shorten that to the following:

```
session.query(MyTable).options(defer(col.name) 
      for col.name in MyTable.__table__.columns
      if col.name not in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

Because `MyTable` has a few extra `column_property`s which aren't listed in `MyTable.__table__.columns`, these get included in the query even though I don't want them.

So is there a construct to express what I want directly as a restriction?
e.g. something like

```
session.query(MyTable).options(XXselect('col1', 'col2', 'col3'))
```

Comment: There is this suggestion which uses defer_everything_but() in this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977658/sqlalchemy-selecting-which-columns-of-an-object-in-a-query/6977901#6977901. I stumbled on this question because I wanted to follow a relationship, which requires the full object. But I didn't want to select all the columns (for example, if the user doesn't have read privileges on all the columns). I don't know of any other way to follow a relationship from just the keyedtuples,

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the values, you can just call :

```
session.query(Mytable.col1, MyTable.col2, MyTable.col3).
```

If you want the full object with deferred columns, `MyTable.__table__.columns` should give you all the columns regardless of the mixins.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct in saying that MyTable.__table__.columns includes mixins ..... in fact the extra columns are appearing in the query because of a column_property. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I won't be able to help you. The only other idea I have is using `deferred` on each column, but that doesn't sound like a good idea. Also, maybe adding the your table definition with the column_property might help (from what I have seen, there are different ways to use it).

Answer (score 0):

[load_only()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#load-only-cols) function can be used for this

> An arbitrary set of columns can be selected as “load only” columns, which will be loaded while deferring all other columns on a given entity, using orm.load_only():

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_only

session.query(Book).options(load_only("summary", "excerpt"))
```