# Get sqlalchemy base class object instead of children

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, sqlalchemy

I have three classes in my model, which one class inherited by the other two:

```
class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Unicode(300))
    type = Column(Unicode(50))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type
    }


class Note(Item):
    __tablename__ = 'note'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True)
    extra = Column(Text)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'note'
    }


class Task(Item):
    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'), primary_key=True)
    another_extra = Column(Text)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'task'
    }
```

So, when I execute `session.query(Item).all()` I get a list that includes both `Note` and `Task` objects, but I don't want that, I want my objects to be the instance of `Item` class and just have `id`, `title`, `type`, not those extra fields. how should I write the query?

to clarify more, currently, I get:

```
[
     <models.Note object at 0x7f25ac3ffe80>,
     <models.Task object at 0x7f25ac3ffe80>,
     <models.Task object at 0x7f25ac3ffe80>,
     ...
]
```

But I want to get:

```
[
    <models.Item object at 0x000000000000>,
    <models.Item object at 0x000000000000>,
    <models.Item object at 0x000000000000>,
    ...
]
```

Comment: Would it be enough to just [query for those specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6977901/6560549) and get a named tuple back? Or do you absolutely need to receive an `Item` type back?

Comment: @SuperShoot I need them to be an instance of `Item` class. Thanks for the like by the way.

Comment: Not sure if it will help you, but I noticed that if you remove the polymorphic identities it works as you expect.

Comment: The code doesn't run for me (getting: "No such polymorphic_identity 'type' is defined")(?) but per the docs I think `just_item = with_polymorphic(Item, [Note, Task])` then followed by: `session.query(just_item).all()` may work? See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance_loading.html

Comment: @HansBouwmeester `with_polymorphic(Item, [Note, Task])` ensures that when querying on the base class, the attributes belonging to the the list of classes (`Note` and `Task` in this example) are eager loaded so that the resultant objects will not have to lazy load attribute values later. The objects returned from that query will still be `Note` and `Task` objects.

Comment: Given the level of interest in this question, did you consider taking it to the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sqlalchemy)? Or have you found a solution that you are using?

Comment: @SuperShoot, for now, I just remove `polymorphic` from classes and just use inheritance without polymorphism, but still actively looking for a better solution.

Comment: @SuperShoot any updates?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE: This may be problematic in a multi-threaded application.**

You could use a context manager to temporarily block the polymorphism:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from sqlalchemy import inspect

@contextmanager
def no_poly(class_):
    mapper = inspect(class_).mapper
    polycol = mapper.polymorphic_on
    mapper.polymorphic_on = None
    yield class_
    mapper.polymorphic_on = polycol

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
task = Task(title='Task Title', another_extra='something')
s = Session()
s.add(task)
s.commit()

# opening a new session as if the pk already exists in the 
# identity map it will return whatever type that pk is 
# pointing at.
s = Session() 
with no_poly(Item) as class_:
    inst = s.query(class_).all()
    print(inst)  # [<__main__.Item object at 0x000001443685DDD8>]
s = Session()  # new session again.
inst = s.query(Item).all()
print(inst)  #  [<__main__.Task object at 0x00000144368770B8>]
```

Something to be mindful of and as noted in the comments in my example, if the identity of the object is already referenced in the [Identity Map](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache), then you will get back whatever type is held in there, regardless of the class that you query on.

Comment: This seems like it might pose some risks in multithreaded programs, since it modifies the mapper in place.

Comment: IIja is correct, I don't really want to modify `mapper`, I was just looking for a query or `__mapper_args__` to work somehow.

Comment: @IljaEverilä do you have any idea about how to achive this?

Comment: Yeh, it's not threadsafe. I'll note that in the answer. Is that a prerequisite in this case?